# Inserting values in DataFrame according to column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My original DataFrame looks like this:

| windcodes | name | matu | CLAUSE | WEIGHTEDRT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 163197.SH | shangguo comp | 2.9248 | NO | 2.582 |
| 154563.SH | guosheng comp | 2.886 | YES | 2.773 |
| 789645.IB | guoyou comp |  | YES | 3.098 |
| 1880260.IB | shagui comp |  | YES | 2.657 |

What I want to do now is that for every row if CLAUSE equal to yes, then substitute the matu value of that row with its WEIGHTEDRT value, and if CLAUSE equal to NO then just leave the original matu and weightedrt as they were.

I wish my outcome DataFrame to be look like this:

| windcodes | name | matu | CLAUSE | WEIGHTEDRT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 163197.SH | shangguo comp | 2.9248 | NO | 2.582 |
| 154563.SH | guosheng comp | 2.773 | YES | 2.773 |
| 789645.IB | guoyou comp | 3.098 | YES | 3.098 |
| 1880260.IB | shagui comp | 2.657 | YES | 2.657 |

Answer (score 2):

```
clause_yes = df['CLAUSE'] == 'YES'
df.loc[clause_yes, 'matu'] = df.loc[clause_yes, 'WEIGHTEDRT']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.where` here:

```py
df.assign(matu = df.matu.where(df.CLAUSE.eq('NO'), df.WEIGHTEDRT))
 
    windcodes           name    matu CLAUSE  WEIGHTEDRT
0   163197.SH  shangguo comp  2.9248     NO       2.582
1   154563.SH  guosheng comp  2.7730    YES       2.773
2   789645.IB    guoyou comp  3.0980    YES       3.098
3  1880260.IB    shagui comp  2.6570    YES       2.657
```

You can also use `np.where` too:

```py
df.assign(matu = np.where(df.CLAUSE.eq('YES'), # condition
                          df.WEIGHTEDRT,  # result if True
                          df.matu)) # result if False

 
    windcodes           name    matu CLAUSE  WEIGHTEDRT
0   163197.SH  shangguo comp  2.9248     NO       2.582
1   154563.SH  guosheng comp  2.7730    YES       2.773
2   789645.IB    guoyou comp  3.0980    YES       3.098
3  1880260.IB    shagui comp  2.6570    YES       2.657
```